# How inside of laravel methods use javascript vars in javascript code?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have simple javascript code:

```
var photo = data.photo;
console.log("{{url('" + photo + "')}}");
```

Here I use laravel `url()` method. But I can't display value `photo` inside laravel method. How I can display it?

Comment: use `console.log(photo)`

Comment: I must get full url with photo var value @Sohel0415

Comment: It's the server which transforms templates like `{{url(stuff)}}` into `http://someurl`, but this code does not run on the server, it's all client-side.

Comment: For example `http://domain.loc/uploads/photo.jpg`

Comment: So, I can't display using `url()` javascript var, yes @James ?

Comment: Right - `url()` is a laravel/php function, you can't do it with javascript.  If `data` is coming from the server (eg, Ajax) you have an opportunity to use `url()` in the code that handles the ajax request.

Comment: @MaxNet you can do it if your JS is in some `.blade.php` file and it will work, but it's a bad practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bad practice to mix Blade syntax with JS. You should do something like this in one of Blade templates:

```
<script>
    let window.url = {{ url('/') }}
</script>
```

Then in JS files use this variable:

```
var photo = data.photo;
console.log(window.url + photo);
```

You'll find [another related code example](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#do-not-put-js-and-css-in-blade-templates-and-do-not-put-any-html-in-php-classes) in my Laravel best practices repo.

Comment: Thanks, @Alexey Mezenin! I'll see to your `Laravel best practices` book.

Comment: Alexey what a good practice for get url to javascriprt var in blade?

Comment: I must create hidden input or div's and get value from HTML code?

Comment: Or I can use in javascript file `var siteurl = "{{url('/')}}";` code?

Comment: I think what using `{{ url('/') }}` in javascript code will be not work.

Comment: @MaxNet it will work in Blade template as I've shown in my answer. If you want to pass some data from Laravel to JS, then you can do `var window.siteurl = {{ url('/') }}` in some Blade file. But keep the rest of JS code in `.js` files.

Comment: Well, I've understood you Alexey! Thank you again for your advice and for your reply to my questions.